# Draw an arbitrary number of lines on a protovis chart

Tags: javascript, data-visualization, protovis, pentaho-ctools, ccc

## My goal

I'm trying to add an arbitrary number of vertical lines to my chart in protovis.  Given an array of x-intercept values, I'd like to loop over this array and draw a vertical line for every intercept value.  Right now, I'm able to draw a fixed number of lines, but am having trouble generalizing.

## What I've done

I've made a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sanp/7v604rq7/16/) showing how I can add a fixed number of lines to a graph, and also reproduced that code below.  Here, I've added 2 lines by explicitly coding `x_value0` and `x_value1`.  In the code, there are two pieces of protovis code that are relevant, which I've labelled `Section A` and `Section B`.  `Section A` is a protovis function which defines where the line will be drawn, and `Section B` calls those functions.

```
// X intercept values hard coded
var x_value0 = 30;
var x_value1 = 70;

new pvc.MetricDotChart({
    canvas:   "cccExample",
    width:    500,
    height:   400,
    axisGrid: true,
    axisZeroLine: false,
    selectable: true,

    extensionPoints: {

        plot_add: function() {
            var panel = new pv.Panel()
                // Quadrant rules above grid, but below dots.
                .zOrder(-1)

                ////
                // Section A Begin
                ////

                // Line 1
                .def('l0', function() {
                    var ccc = this.getContext();
                    var scale = ccc.chart.axes.base.scale;
                    var li = ccc.panel._layoutInfo;
                    return li.paddings.left + scale(x_value0);
                })

                // Line 2
                .def('l1', function() {
                    var ccc = this.getContext();
                    var scale = ccc.chart.axes.base.scale;
                    var li = ccc.panel._layoutInfo;
                    return li.paddings.left + scale(x_value1);
                })

                ////
                // Section A End
                ////

            ;

        ////
        // Section B Begin
        ////   

        // Line 1
            panel
            .add(pv.Rule)
            .top(0)
            .left  (function() { return this.parent.l0();     })
            .height(function() { return this.parent.height(); })
            .width(null)
            ;      

        // Line 2
            panel
            .add(pv.Rule)
            .top(0)
            .left  (function() { return this.parent.l1();     })
            .height(function() { return this.parent.height(); })
            .width(null)
            ;            

        ////
        // Section B End
        ////               

            return panel;      

        }
    }
})

.setData(testLDot2)
.render();
```

What I'd like to do instead is define `xvalues` as an array, and loop over that.  I'm kind of half way there in my attempt.  I made a [second jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sanp/7v604rq7/17/) where I try to move the `xvalues` into an array.  The problem is that I can't seem to successfully wrap the relevant part in a for-loop.  The code from that jsfiddle is:

```
// X intercept values in an array
var x_values = [30, 60];

new pvc.MetricDotChart({
    canvas:   "cccExample",
    width:    500,
    height:   400,
    axisGrid: true,
    axisZeroLine: false,
    selectable: true,

    extensionPoints: {

        plot_add: function() {
            var panel = new pv.Panel()
                // Quadrant rules above grid, but below dots.
                .zOrder(-1)

                ////
                // Section A Begin - How can I put this inside of a loop?
                ////

                // Line 1
                .def('l0', function() {
                    var ccc = this.getContext();
                    var scale = ccc.chart.axes.base.scale;
                    var li = ccc.panel._layoutInfo;
                    return li.paddings.left + scale(x_values[0]);
                })

                // Line 2
                .def('l1', function() {
                    var ccc = this.getContext();
                    var scale = ccc.chart.axes.base.scale;
                    var li = ccc.panel._layoutInfo;
                    return li.paddings.left + scale(x_values[1]);
                })

                ////
                // Section A End
                ////

            ;

        ////
        // Section B Begin - I'm able to successfully loop this part
        ////   

            for (i = 0; i < x_values.length; i++) {
                // The name of the .def function defined above
                var fn_name = 'this.parent.l' + i + '()';
                // Draw the lines
                    panel
                    .add(pv.Rule)
                    .top(0)
                    .left  (function() { return eval(fn_name);     })
                    .height(function() { return this.parent.height(); })
                    .width(null)
;      

            }

        ////
        // Section B End
        ////               

            return panel;      

        }
    }
})

.setData(testLDot2)
.render();
```

I'm able to wrap `Section B` inside of a for-loop, and I'd like to do something similar for `Section A`:

```
for (i = 0; i < x_values.length; i++) {
    .def('l'+i, function() {
        var ccc = this.getContext();
        var scale = ccc.chart.axes.base.scale;
        var li = ccc.panel._layoutInfo;
        return li.paddings.left + scale(x_values[i]);
    })
}
```

or something similar.  But the problem is that protovis doesn't seem to allow me to put any code around this `.def` block.

I've also tried generating a string for each item in the `x_values` array, which contains the definition of the `Section A` function, and then calling it inside of the protovis code using `eval()`, but that hasn't worked so far.

Any help here would be greatly appreciated!

## Edit - more progress

I seem to have gotten closer to what I want by eliminating `Section A` and moving that function inside of `Section B`.  See [my latest jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sanp/7v604rq7/19/) for that code.  Previously, in `Section B`, the `.left` line called one of the functions defined in `Section A`.  Instead, I moved that function's definition inside of the `.left` line of code, like so:

```
////
// Section B Begin
////   

for (var i = 0; i < x_values.length; i++) {
    var x = x_values[i];
    // Lines
    panel
    .add(pv.Rule)
    .top(0)
    .left  (function() {                 
        var ccc = this.parent.getContext();
        var scale = ccc.chart.axes.base.scale;
        var li = ccc.panel._layoutInfo;
        return li.paddings.left + scale(x);                                     
    })
    .height(function() { return this.parent.height(); })
    .width(null)
    ;      
}
```

This is running now, but still not quite right: it's only drawing the last line in the `x_values` array and overwriting all previous ones.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace your loop by the following code

```
panel
    .add(pv.Rule)
    .data(x_values)
    .top(0)
    .left  (
        function(d) {                 
        this.index * 20 + 15
        var ccc = this.parent.getContext();
        var scale = ccc.chart.axes.base.scale;
        var li = ccc.panel._layoutInfo;
        return li.paddings.left + scale(d);                                     
    })
    .height(function() { return this.parent.height(); })
    .width(null)
    ;
```

Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/f9uhzaz9/